# Remove variable from the index.php url ?categoryID=27/index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, cnc

I have url: `https://example.com/index.php?categoryID=127/index.php`
Write htacces:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.php(.*)$ /$1$2 [R=301,L]
```

And I got `https://example.com/?categoryID=127/index.php`

How can I remove the index.php after the variable? Must use htaccess or need to change the root index.php url by dint of php?
How can do that?

Comment: Hello. I don't know what you're trying, but your URL structure looks completly wrong. Why do you have a `index.php?category=XX/INDEX.PHP`??? The second index.php souldn't be there, that doesn't make any sense. You already specified the file you're look at with the first index.php?cat... so you can't look at two files at the same time. Also, index.php isn't a directory, so there can't be a index.php inside of index.php

Comment: Hello. I agree that it should not be. But there is and I'm trying to get rid of duplicate url ((  https://example.com/?categoryID=127/index.php  and https://example.com/?categoryID=127  open the same page